# How customize tooltip text in Google Geo Chart

Tags: javascript, tooltip, google-visualization

I need remove first empty string in tooltip.
I'm used formater, for change first string to '', but I'm can't remove it. If I change '' to null then in first string shows first column data.

[image]

Code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'State');
data.addColumn('number', 'TempNumber');
data.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip'
});
data.addRows([
    ['Ohio', 0, 'Ohio'],
    ...
]);
var options = {
    width:      580,
    region:     'US',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    colorAxis:  {colors: ['#abb7df']},
    legend:     'none'
};
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
var formatter = new google.visualization.PatternFormat('');
    formatter.format(data, [0,1,2]);

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: If the answer below worked for you, please click the check mark below the up/down-vote arrows in the answer so that other people can see that this solved your issue. If my answer was not clear enough, or if you are still having issues, please add a comment to the answer explaining what that issue is/what isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to currently do this (without drawing your own tooltip function to draw the boxes). In the future, hopefully they will implement [isHtml: true](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content) to geocharts, but right now it isn't supported.

Tooltip cannot do what you want it to do in its current implementation. You can reduce text size, but that will also reduce the size of the text you want shown. You can change color, but again it affects the entire tooltip. There isn't really much you can do to fix the issue rather than implement your own form of tooltipping (creating a function that will take the column 0 value of whatever your mouse is over, and display it either in a separate  in the page, or have it calculate where your mouse is and show it there).

Comment: Thanks jmac!
Has eliminated the need for the implementation of the written above. Client wanted to remove the tooltips. If they are needed again, I'll try to hang on the event mouseover.